# find overlapped axis-aligned rectangles

Tags: algorithm

I am solving [this problems](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3324880/1082727) - how to find overlapping axis aligned rectangles.
I have question about standard solution to this problem.

At some point we need to build binary search tree to get points which fall in to interval, particularly y-interval of a current left edge we are processing. But this way we cannot capture intersection when big rectangle fully contains smaller one. when we hit left edge on the small rectangle, y-boundary of the big rectangle will not fall in to the range of y-boundary of the small one.
Could somebody explain me how to find overlapping rectangles in the moment we process some left edge ( in sweeping process). Thank you!

Comment: In that case would you not already have encountered the larger rectangle when you get to the smaller one?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Why? If there is a small rectangle inside a big one, then when we hit left side of small rectangle then big rectangle is active so it will present in the binary search tree. The question is how to recognize this overlapping? y-boundaries of big rectangle is not in the range of y-boundaries of small one.