# Fast algorithm for testing if every rectangle built using any two points from a list contains a third point from that list

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry

The problem is as it follows:

Given N (N <= 100,000) points by their Cartesian coordinates, test if every rectangle (with an area > 0) built using any two of them contains at least another point from that list either inside the rectangle or on his margin.

I know the algorithm for `O(N^2)` time complexity. I want to find the solution for `O(N * logN)`. Memory is not a problem.

When I say two points define a rectangle, I mean that those two points are in two of its opposite corners. The sides of the rectangles are parallel to the Cartesian axes.

Here are two examples:

```
N = 4

Points:

1 1

3 5

2 4

8 8
```

**INCORRECT**: (the rectangle (1, 1) - (2, 4) doesn't have any point inside of it or on its margin).

```
N = 3

Points:

10 9

13 9

10 8
```

**CORRECT**.

Comment: A line-segment can be defined by 2 points, doesn't a rectangle (a plane) need at least 3 points?

Comment: When I say 2 points define a rectangle, I mean that those 2 points are in 2 of his opposite corners.

Comment: Ok then I think your problem statement should say that right up front, thats not an obvious assumption.

Comment: @BruceDean But as you point out, there's no *other* way to define a rectangle using only two points, so it *is* kind of an obvious assumption; you may be confused by the fact that you can't define a plane in 3D space using only 2 points. The more important assumption, I think, is that the sides of the rectangles are parallel to the cartesian axes.

Comment: @Kyle: In theory, a rectangle could be defined from a half-diagonal: corner and centre.  However, in that case, order is important.

Comment: @rossum True, I suppose, but that's a non-obvious representation. You could just as well define a rectangle using a center point plus a "shape-vector" represented as a point such that the vector from the origin to the point is equivalent to one of the vectors across the diagonal of the rectangle.

Comment: Can you explain the last example?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Note the "area > 0" requirement....

Comment: What's this for? Part of some triangulation algorithm?

Comment: possible duplicate of [axis‐aligned rectangles intersection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3324880/axis-aligned-rectangles-intersection)

Comment: Ok, the question I linked is actually a bit different and if used directly is of complexity `O(n^2*log(n))`, so it is not a perfect duplicate. Maybe you could build a set of rectangles smaller than every possible pair and then use this algorithm. (Maybe similar as in *Kyle Stand*'s answer. I'm not perfectly sure this works though.)

Comment: Are you even sure there is a `O(n*log(n))` answer? The naive algorithm would require to generate all possible `O(n^2)` rectangles and then do all select all possible pairs of rectangles which yields `O(n^4)`, (The last step could be reduced to `O(n*log(n)`, so the slighty improved version would have `O(n^2*log(n^2))` ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every point `P = (a, b)` in the set, search the nearest points of the form `Y = (x, b)` and `X = (a, y)` such that `x > a` and `y > b`.

Then, find if the rectangle defined by the two points `X, Y` contains any<sup>*</sup> internal point `R` <strike>besides `P`, `X` and `Y`</strike>. If that is the case, it's easy to see that the rectangle `P, R` does not contain any other point in the set.

If no point in the set exists matching the restrictions for X or Y, then you have to use `(a, ∞)` or `(∞, b)` respectively instead.

The computational cost of the algorithm is O(NlogN):

- Looking for `X` or `Y` can be done using binary search [O(logN)] over a presorted list [O(NlogN)].
- Looking for R can be done using some spatial tree structure as a quadtree or a k-d tree [O(logN)].

*) If `X, Y` contains more than one internal point, R should be selected as the nearest to P.

**Update**: the algorithm above works for rectangles defined by its botton-left and upper-right corners. In order to make it work also for rectangles defined by its botton-right and upper-left corners, a new point `X'` (such that it is the nearest one to P of the form `X' = (a, y')` where `y' < b`) and the corresponding rectangle defined by `X', Y` should also be considered for every point in the set.

Comment: I think your idea has some flaws. For example, **it's easy to see that the rectangle P, R does not contain any other point in the set** it's not always the case, as if we have 4 points, each of them in a different corner of a rectangle, it's still correct, while your algorithm decides that it's not. Nevertheless, I'm quite sure you're close to the solution (or I just didn't understand what you explained). Could you please explain your idea and WHY does it work? Just the idea, not the implementation. I can handle that. Thank you very very much!

Comment: @Rutherford1337: Actually the condition is that the point R should be internal to `X, Y`. I have corrected my response.

Comment: But why does this algorithm work? Can you please post some kind of short proof?

Comment: @Rutherford1337: there was another flaw on my solution, I have updated my post again. Regarding why it works, it is pretty obvious, just try it a dozens times with pencil and paper and you will also see it. Otherwise, just ask again and I would try to explain it, but really, I think it is easier to understand just *seeing* it work!

Comment: Can you give me a hint on how to fast determine the nearest point?

Comment: @Rutherford1337: using some spatial tree structure, a quad tree or a k-d tree.

Answer (score 2):

Sort the points in order of the *max* of their coordinate pairs, from lowest to highest (`O(n*log(n))`). Starting with the lower-left point (lowest max coordinate), if the next point in the ordering *does not share* either  the original point's x-value or its y-value (e.g. `(1,2)` and `(5,2)` share a `y`-coordinate of `2`, but `(1,2)` and `(2, 1)` have neither coordinate in common), the set of points fails the test. Otherwise, move to the next point. If you reach the final point in this way (`O(n)`), the set is valid. The algorithm overall is `O(n*log(n))`.

#### Explanation

Two points that share a coordinate value lie along a line parallel to one of the axes, so there is no rectangle drawn between them (since such a rectangle would have area=0).

For a given point *p1*, if the next "bigger" point in the ordering, *p2*, is directly vertical or horizontal from *p1* (i.e. it shares a coordinate value), then all points to the upper-right of *p2* form rectangles with *p1* that include *p2*, so there are no rectangles in the set that have *p1* as the lower-left corner and lack an internal point.

If, however, the next-bigger point is diagonal from *p2*, then the *p1* <-> *p2* rectangle has no points from the set inside it, so the set is invalid.

Comment: I suppose you meant O(N * logN). Anyway, could you please explain why this works? Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure your method works. For instance `(0,0), (4,0), (0,4), (3, 3), (3, 4), (4, 3)` which sum `0, 4, 4, 6, 7, 7` respectively. `(0, 0)-(3, 3)` does not contain any point inside, while `(0, 4)-(3, 3)` contains `(3, 4)`.

Comment: @salva I think it needs to be the larger coordinate, then; I've adjusted my answer accordingly. However, your example would fail the original test anyway, because switching the coordinates (e.g. 4,0 to 0,4) does *not* count as sharing a coordinate value.

Comment: Actually, you might just need to sort the points twice, once by x-value and once by y-value.