# Group pairs of intersecting rectangles

Tags: algorithm

I have a collection of intersecting rectangles. Using a line sweep algorithm i calcuated the pairs of every intersecting rectangles . Now I would like an efficient algorithm to  group all intersecting rectangles, something similar to finding islands.
Input: (1,2) (2,3) (3,4) (5,6) (6,7) -> Pairs calculated by line sweep algorithm.
Ouput: (1,2,3,4)( 5,6,7)

For line sweep i referred to [axis‐aligned rectangles intersection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3324880/axis-aligned-rectangles-intersection)

Comment: Start small: If you have just two rectangles, can you write some code to tell whether they're intersecting?

Comment: You need the algorithm in pseudocode or in some particular language?

Comment: Sorry my question was misleading. I edited the question

Comment: Can you give the link to the algorithm you referred for finding pairs of every intersecting rectangles?

Comment: https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/notes/disjoint-set-union-union-find/

Answer (score 2):

To make union set for all connected rectangles using pairs of intersected ones, you can exploit very effective algorithmic approach with  [disjoint-set/union–find data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure).